# Django Foreign Key Relationship is giving Error in Django Restful

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have two Models which they are related together; StaffProfile and Department. The department is a foreign key in StaffProfile which means all Staff must have a department. Now, I want to fetch a department and populate all the staff under the department, by fetching department ID to get it

models.py

```
class StaffProfile(models.Model):

    SEX = (
        ('1', 'Male'),
        ('2', 'Female')
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_staff', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_by  = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='created_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    staff_details =  models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='staff_details', null=True)
    phonenumber = models.CharField("Phone Number Use", max_length=50, null=True)
    passport = models.ImageField("Passport Photography", upload_to='staff/', validators=[validate_file_size, validate_file_extension02], null=True)
    address = models.CharField('Contact Address', max_length=250, null=True)
    country = models.CharField('Country', max_length=50, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField("Date of Birth", default="2019-06-04", null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(70),MinValueValidator(18)], default=18)
    sex = models.CharField(choices=SEX, default="Male", max_length=50)
    login = models.BooleanField("Check First time Login", default=False)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Staff Profile"
        verbose_name_plural = "Staff Profiles"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
    
    @property
    def staff_details_name(self):
        return f'{self.staff_details.name} - {self.staff_details.company.name}'
    
    
    def sex_name(self):
        return self.get_sex_display()



class Department(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company', related_name='department_company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField('Department Name in A Compnay', max_length=250)
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Department"
        verbose_name_plural = "Departments"

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} - {self.company.name} - {self.company.floor.name}
```

serializers.py

```
class StaffDepartmentDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = StaffProfile
        fields = '__all__'


class StaffDepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

   
  

    class Meta:
        model = Department
        fields = ('pk', 'staff_details_name',)
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def staff_department(request, pk):
    department = get_object_or_404(Department, pk=pk)
    print(department)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = StaffDepartmentSerializer(department)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```